# Where will my errors be recorded when running a php script using exec()? exec('php script.php > /dev/null &');

Tags: php, redirect, exec

I have a background script that will be exectued by a web script.  It will take longer to run than the web script, so I want it to complete it's job in the background.

I should make no output so I have the > /dev/null to redirect the output and then the & I believe makes it run in the background.

but if the script encounters an error, where will this error be recorded?

Sorry for the noob question.  I'm not too familiar with exec or with cli php

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your installation, I'm on Linux and installed Lampp, and all my log messages are at `/lammp/logs`

Comment: Thanks!   So just to be clear, the error messages will appear in the same place where all other php error message appear including web php scripts run from a browser?

Comment: it will also depend if in your web application you have set the error_log to work as you wish: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php